# Find posterior distribution given a prior normal and a normal rv

Tags: bayesian, posterior

Suppose $X$ has $N(\theta, \phi)$ distribution for a known $\phi$. Suppose that the prior distribution for $\theta$ is $N(\theta_0, \phi_0)$ (both parameters known).

The question asks me to find the posterior distribution of $\theta$ given $X = x$.

Well, I applied the formula to get:

$\pi(\theta | x) \propto f(x|\theta) \times \pi(\theta)$

$\pi(\theta | x) \propto exp (\frac{-(x - \theta)^2}{2 \phi}) \times exp(-\frac{-(\theta - \theta_0)^2}{2 \phi_0})$ (is that correct?)

$\pi(\theta | x) \propto exp(\frac{2x\theta - \theta^2}{2 \phi} + \frac{2\theta \theta_0 - \theta^2}{2\phi_0})$

But that does not seem to simplify nicely. Can someone help me to conclude this?

Comment: Try completing the square (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) so that you obtain $(\theta - m)^2/v$ inside the exponential function. From there you can try to identify to which distribution this is proportional to.

Comment: For more answers related to this question visit the hits for [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normal+prior+complete+square+is%3Aanswer+score%3A2).